# Expect - how to set output from $expect_out(0,string) as variable and use it further

Tags: expect

I am totally new to the Expect ... I need to write a script which will telnet to the MS server, displays current sessions there and logoff specific user. Script attached.

```
#!/bin/bash

# execute expect part
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
#
# telnet to PC
#
spawn telnet 9.9.9.9;
expect "login:";
send "admin\r";
expect "password:";
send "admin\r";
expect "*>";
send "Query session test\r";
expect -re " \[0-9] ";
set val [\$expect_out(0,string)];
send "logoff $val\r";
send "\r";
expect "*>";
send "\x1d";
expect "*>";
send "q\r";
exit 1;
EOF;
```

I can't get it working. It seems I'm doing something wrong with defining the variable. When I run the script I'm getting the following result:

```
C:\Users\admin>Query session test                                         
SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
rdp-tcp#0         test                      3  Active  rdpwd

C:\Users\admin>invalid command name " 3 "
while executing
"$expect_out(0,string)"
invoked from within
"set val [$expect_out(0,string)]"
```

Btw when I used send_user in the script instead, I got correct input in the telnet session, but from some reason it is not accepting it as command at all.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Expect will treat things between matching brackets as a command.

`set val [\$expect_out(0,string)]` means executing a command named **$expect_out(0,string)** (in this case, it's **3**.) and assigning the command output to **val**. That's why the output shows `invalid command name " 3 "` because there is no such command.

Change the line to `set val $expect_out(0,string)` and I believe things would get better.

BTW, `send_user` is just something like `puts`. It only prints message to the standard output, not the spawned process.

Comment: @user3770336, you might want to run through the Tcl tutorial to get a better handle on the language:  http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html